# getting null values back from SQL lite db

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, null

I've been playing with a sample application I found online. Just changing things to see how it works. Yesterday this was not an issue. Today is a different story. I seem to write the correct info to the db. I've checked through log outputs. When I return the information through a cursor I get "null". So, say I enter "Eggs","Bread", and "Candy". I get back "null","null", and "null".

It all starts with the listener for the add grocery button. Adds to the db and writes the list to an label.

Any help?

```
  private void addEvent(String title) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Log.v(TAG, "Adding " + title);
    values.put(EventsDataSQLHelper.TITLE, title);
            db.insert(EventsDataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, values);

  }

  private Cursor getEvents() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(EventsDataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, null, null, null,
        null, EventsDataSQLHelper.TITLE);    
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;
  }

  private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {            
      String title = cursor.getString(1);
      ret.append(title + "\n");
      Log.v(TAG, "SHOWING RET VARIABLE" + ret);
    }
    t.setText(ret);   

  }
  View.OnClickListener myhandler = new View.OnClickListener()
  {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View GLview) 
        {
            EditText eT = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemName1);
            editTextStr = eT.getText().toString();
            Log.v(TAG, editTextStr);
            if(editTextStr != null)
            {
                addEvent(editTextStr.toString());
                Cursor cursor = getEvents();
                showEvents(cursor);             
                eT.setText(null);
            }
        }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure cursor points to the first element of the result cursor.moveToFirst();
Then call cursor.moveToNext()